# getElementsByClassName vs querySelctorAll second iteration doesnt work

Tags: javascript, dom

I am wondering why it skips the second iteration when I am using `document.getElementsByClassName`?

```js
var sameClass = document.querySelectorAll("p.kokos");

for ( var i = 0; i < sameClass.length; i++){
  sameClass[i].className = "cool";
}

var newClass = document.getElementsByClassName("new");

for ( var i = 0 ; i<= newClass.length; i++){
  newClass[i].className = "red";
}
```

```css
.lw { font-size: 60px; }


.cool {
  color: #00FFFF;
}
.red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<p class="kokos" id = "test">Hello Weaver!</p>
 <p class="kokos" id = "test">Hello Weaver!</p>
 <p class="kokos" id = "test">Hello Weaver!</p>
 <p class="new" id = "test">Hello Weaver!</p>
 <p class="new" id = "test">Hello Weaver!</p>
 <p class="new" id = "test">Hello Weaver!</p>
```

Comment: Use `i < newClass.length` instead of `i <= newClass.length`. Also, do not use the same ID twice. Also consider using `forEach` instead.

Comment: even if i change the i < newClass.length it still doesnt work with for loop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`document.getElementsByClassName()` returns a ***live*** HTMLCollection.  That means that as you modify the objects in the collection so that they no longer match the class name, the actual HTMLCollection object gets modified right out from under you, affecting your iteration.

One popular work-around is to iterate the collection in reverse order from back to front.  That way, if the current element is removed from the collection, the rest of your iteration is not affected.

```
var newClass = document.getElementsByClassName("new");

for (var i = newClass.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
    newClass[i].className = "red";
}
```

Another work-around is to make a copy of the HTMLCollection into a normal array and iterate that array instead.

`document.querySelectorAll()` returns a fixed collection, not a live collection so it does not have this issue.

Answer (score 1):

It's because `newClass` is not a static array of nodes as you might assume.  It's a live [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection).  What that means is that if you change the underlying attribute which makes one of the elements a part of that collection, it will no longer be a part of that collection.  Think of it like this:

You're in a crowd of people wearing hats.  You see three people wearing blue hats and you call them the "Blue Hats".  You then go to the first person and give him a red hat and tell him to wear it.  Now if you look at that same crowd, you might expect there to be three "Blue Hats", but there's only two now.  The person who changed his hat is still there, he's just not a "Blue Hat" now and your collection of "Blue Hats" is smaller.

That's what's happening with your list.  After the first loop, you no longer have the first element.  `i` has incremented, so it goes to the second element in the list, but the list changed (by losing the first element), so you're really going to the third element instead.  Using the analogy, you've now asked for the second person with a blue hat, which is actually the third person from the original three.  He is also the second person in your *current* list of blue hat wearing people.

In the below example you can see that the number of elements has decremented because you changed the thing that made the first element in the list a part of the list:

```js
var sameClass = document.querySelectorAll("p.kokos");

for ( var i = 0; i < sameClass.length; i++){
  sameClass[i].className = "cool";
}

var newClass = document.getElementsByClassName("new");

newClass[0].className = "red";

console.log(newClass.length)
```

```css
.lw { font-size: 60px; }


.cool {
  color: #00FFFF;
}
.red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<p class="kokos" id = "test">Hello Weaver!</p>
 <p class="kokos" id = "test">Hello Weaver!</p>
 <p class="kokos" id = "test">Hello Weaver!</p>
 <p class="new" id = "test">Hello Weaver!</p>
 <p class="new" id = "test">Hello Weaver!</p>
 <p class="new" id = "test">Hello Weaver!</p>
```

And in this final snippet, I've used a trick to force your HTMLCollection to be an array instead which is not a live list.  The result is that your list doesn't change and all three elements are iterated over:

```js
var sameClass = document.querySelectorAll("p.kokos");

for ( var i = 0; i < sameClass.length; i++){
  sameClass[i].className = "cool";
}

var newClass = [].slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName("new"));

for ( var i = 0 ; i< newClass.length; i++){
  newClass[i].className = "red";
}
```

```css
.lw { font-size: 60px; }


.cool {
  color: #00FFFF;
}
.red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<p class="kokos" id = "test">Hello Weaver!</p>
 <p class="kokos" id = "test">Hello Weaver!</p>
 <p class="kokos" id = "test">Hello Weaver!</p>
 <p class="new" id = "test">Hello Weaver!</p>
 <p class="new" id = "test">Hello Weaver!</p>
 <p class="new" id = "test">Hello Weaver!</p>
```